# Scraping lineup data from play by play using R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with basketball play by play and I want to create "lineup" columns containing lists for summarization later. Here's a sample data:

```
        game_id team_id opp_team_id player_id period secs_remaining  action_type action_subtype
     <int>   <int>       <int>     <int>  <int>          <int>        <chr>          <chr>
1     1475       5           8       587      1            720 substitution             in
2     1475       5           8        66      1            720 substitution             in
3     1475       5           8       596      1            720 substitution             in
4     1475       5           8       206      1            720 substitution             in
5     1475       5           8       469      1            720 substitution             in
6     1475       8           5       940      1            720 substitution             in
7     1475       8           5       120      1            720 substitution             in
8     1475       8           5       124      1            720 substitution             in
9     1475       8           5      1040      1            720 substitution             in
10    1475       8           5       114      1            720 substitution             in
11    1475      NA          NA        NA      1            720         game          start
12    1475       5           8       469      1            719     jumpball            won
13    1475       8           5       114      1            718     jumpball           lost
14    1475       8           5       120      1            695        steal               
15    1475       5           8       469      1            695     turnover   ballhandling
```

Been trying to experiment with dplyr's mutate() and lists, but been hitting a dead end each time. The expected output data will hopefully have a new column like (I'll use row 1 to 5 as an example):

```
   id    lineup
<int>    <list>
    1    <int [5]> --> contains (587, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
    2    <int [5]> --> contains (587, 66, NULL, NULL, NULL)
    3    <int [5]> --> contains (587, 66, 596, NULL, NULL)
    4    <int [5]> --> contains (587, 66, 596, 206, NULL)
    5    <int [5]> --> contains (587, 66, 596, 206, 469)
```

I understand appending new elements to a list is slow, so if there's a better way to handle this in R, I'd gladly accept any suggestion.

The important part is that it can handle combinations. (i.e. the vector (1,2,3,4,5) should count the same as (2,3,4,5,1) once I summarize it).

Thanks in advance

### Update

Here's an added example that isn't the start of the game

```
  game_id team_id opp_team_id player_id period secs_remaining  action_type action_subtype
    <int>   <int>       <int>     <int>  <int>          <int>        <chr>          <chr>
1    1475       8           5       124      1            369       foulon               
2    1475       5           8       206      1            369 substitution            out
3    1475       5           8       125      1            369 substitution             in
4    1475       8           5      1040      1            369 substitution            out
5    1475       8           5        73      1            369 substitution             in
6    1475       8           5       124      1            358          3pt
```

This was the first substitution after of that game. The lineups for each team should be:

For Team 8: list(940,120,124,1040,114)

For Team 5: list(587,66,596,206,46)

Here's the expected output data (selecting only the lineup column):

```
   id lineup
<int> <list>
    1 <int [5]> --> contains(940,120,124,1040,114) #This isn't a substitute
    2 <int [5]> --> (587,66,596,46) #This was the sub out for Team 5
    3 <int [5]> --> (587,66,596,46,125) #This was the sub in for Team 5
    4 <int [5]> --> (940,120,124,114) #This was the sub out for Team 8
    5 <int [5]> --> (940,120,124,114,73) #This was the sub in for Team 8
    6 <int [5]> --> (940,120,124,114,73) #This isn't a substitute
```

My latest attempt:

```
dat %>%
#Initialize lineup column
mutate(lineup = NA) %>%
mutate(lineup = ifelse(
          #Check if it's the start of the game
          is.na(lag(game_id)) | lag(game_id) != game_id,
          player_id,
          #Check if it's a substitution
          ifelse(
            action_type == 'substitution',
            #Check if it's a sub in or a sub out
            ifelse(
              #Sub in
              action_subtype == 'in',
              "sub in",
              #Sub out
              "sub out"
            ),
            "not a sub"
          )
        ))
```

Comment: What are you searching by? What criteria do you need to return? What code have you written in attempt to obtain this? (Simply stating that you've used `mutate()` doesn't help us dissect your issue) After that information has been obtained you may have more luck in getting an answer.

Comment: @Badger basically, the logic is:

if it's the start of the game: lineup column is the player id (since the first observation of any game ID is a substitution in). 

If it's not the start of the game, you check:

If it's a sub in -- you add the player_id of the current row to the lineup list of the previous row. 

If it's a sub out -- you remove the player_id of the current row to the lineup list of the previous row. 

If it's not a sub in or sub out, just copy the lineup list of the previous row. 

I've edited my current place in my attempts ot use mutate()

Comment: What is the point in creating a `list` rather than just a regular column? And maybe you could make a more illustrative and more minimal example? It seems like complicated things happen when the `action_type` is something other than substitution, but your example output is just 5 substitutions in a row. A good example would have one or two substitutions (more are unnecessary) and then some other action types. An even better example would be easy to copy/paste (use `dput()` to create a copy/pasteable R object).

Comment: @Gregor the point of making the lineup column a list so you can remove and add player_ids as substitutions are made. I'll add another example where it isn't 5 straight substitutions.

Comment: I was able to do this using a for loop through each row and populating the lineup column. But it takes a lot of time (as for loops are inefficient) so I'd still like to try a mutate() solution. 

If not, I might check the data.table package (although I absolutely love the dplyr package)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to make this using the mutate() so I just settled for the loop. Here's the answer, if anyone's looking:

```
calc_lineup <- function(df) {
  lineup <- setNames(list(NA,NA,NA), c("t1", "t1_lineup", "t2_lineup"))
  for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
      if (df[row,]$checker == 'start') {
        #If Start of the Game, 
        lineup$t1 <- df[row,]$team_id
        lineup$t1_lineup <- df[row,]$player_id
        lineup$t2_lineup <- NA

      } else if (df[row,]$checker == 'sub in') {
        if(lineup$t1 == df[row,]$team_id) {
          lineup$t1_lineup %<>% c(df[row,]$player_id)
          lineup$t1_lineup = lineup$t1_lineup[!is.na(lineup$t1_lineup)]
        } else {
          lineup$t2_lineup %<>% c(df[row,]$player_id)
          lineup$t2_lineup = lineup$t2_lineup[!is.na(lineup$t2_lineup)]
        }
      } else if (df[row,]$checker == 'sub out') {
        if(lineup$t1 == df[row,]$team_id) {
          lineup$t1_lineup <- lineup$t1_lineup[lineup$t1_lineup != df[row,]$player_id]
        } else {
          lineup$t2_lineup <- lineup$t2_lineup[lineup$t2_lineup != df[row,]$player_id]
        }
      }
    df[row,]$t1_lineup <- list(lineup$t1_lineup)
    df[row,]$t2_lineup <- list(lineup$t2_lineup)       
  }
  return(df)
}
```